# MYSQL Autoincrement reset after executing alter statement (mysql 5.0.92)

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> describe phppos_sales_suspended;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| sale_time    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| customer_id  | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| employee_id  | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
| comment      | text         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| sale_id      | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| payment_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

After executing the below on an EMPTY table the primary key seems to be reset back to 1. Why is that? I thought that wasn't possible. This doesn't happen in mysql 5.1.54

```
ALTER TABLE  `phppos_sales_suspended` ADD  `deleted` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
ADD INDEX (  `deleted` );

mysql> describe phppos_sales_suspended;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| sale_time    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| customer_id  | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| employee_id  | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
| comment      | text         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| sale_id      | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| payment_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| deleted      | int(1)       | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an index to an InnoDB table rebuilds the table. Not inheriting the old autoincrement value was a bug that's been fixed in your newer version.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34920

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21404